# What is the purpose of a combustion chamber in a jet engine?

Tags: combustion

I've learned that in combustion chamber fuel and air are mixed and burned but I dont understand the outcome. Ive heard that after combustion it is still very hot and I also seen that you loss heat as a result. So can someone clear this up for me so its not so confusing, also if you need to burn the air and fuel mixture why can you just use the hot air from the compressors?

Comment: I don't understand how you are confused.

Comment: "This increase in pressure or volume can be used to do work, for example, to move a piston on a crankshaft or a turbine disc in a gas turbine. If the gas velocity changes, thrust is produced, such as in the nozzle of a rocket engine." Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

the outcome of the mixing and burning of the compressed air and fuel in the "burner cans" is the release of lots of energy, which makes the exhaust gases very hot. those gases then try to accellerate out the back of the engine at great speed, which produces the reaction thrust that propels the airplane.

the reason why the compressor stage fans produce hot air at high pressure to feed the burner cans is that they are forced to spin by a turbine that is in the exhaust gas flow, where it extracts some of the available work out of the exhaust stream. without the work being done on the inlet air by the compressor stage, the inlet air would not be heated up in the first place.

The operating cycle of a jet engine that works like this is called the Brayton cycle and is described in lots more detail on the web.